# Evaluation in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, evaluation

I have an expression assigned to a variable. For example:

```
exp1 = a*x+b
```

Now I would like to plot it using something like this

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[ex99], {x, 0, 1}],
 {a, 0, 1},
 {b, 0, 1}]
```

I can see 'a' and 'b' being properly substituted by 'Evaluate', but Plot does not work as expected. I suspect it has something to do with 'x' substitution. How can I fix that? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Manipulate[Plot[a*x + b, {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]` ?

Comment: You could also try `Manipulate[Plot[a*x+b,{x,0,1},AxesOrigin->{0, 0}],{a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}]` in order to better see the results...

Comment: Even better IMO: `Manipulate[Plot[a*x+b,{x,0,1},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->{{0,1},{-2,2}}], {a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}]`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to define the function using set delayed.

```
ex99[a_, b_, x_] := a*x + b;
Manipulate[Plot[ex99[a, b, x], {x, 0, 1}], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a*x+b,{x,0,1},AxesOrigin->{0,0},PlotRange->{{0,1},{-2,2}}], {a,-1,1},{b,-1,1}]
```

Comment: Of course in this simple example I can copy and paste the expression. In real world my exp1 is result of Integrate and quite complex.

Comment: When you said "Plot does not work as expected" I thought you we're interested in showing how $a$ and $b$ would influence your plot...

Answer (score 1):

Using [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) (a.k.a ";"), you can include expressions within Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
     ex99 = a x + b;
     Plot[ex99, {x, 0, 1}],
     {a, 0, 1},
     {b, 0, 1}
   ]
```

The semicolon ";" is postfix notation for the CompoundExpression command, which has amongst other things the effect of evaluating the command in the kernel without producing output in the front end.